# Web API Read Response on 400

Tags: c#

The Stackoverflow API, if the request is not successful, how to read the response please?

```
using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(handler))
{

    string response = string.Empty;
    response = Client.GetStringAsync(apiUri.Uri).Result;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Questions<Question>>(response);
}
```

When an error occurs:

```
{"error_id":502,"error_message":"too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 82216 seconds","error_name":"throttle_violation"}
```

An error `InnerException = {"Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)."}`

Comment: Suggestion --- if you own the API then change the response code to 429 (Too Many requests) so that caller can identify if API can be retried after definitive time. Suggested answer by @tymtam will details out the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following paragraph is from [Call a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

> HttpClient does not throw an exception when the HTTP response contains an error code. Instead, the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property is false if the status is an error code. If you prefer to treat HTTP error codes as exceptions, call `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode` on the response object. `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` throws an exception if the status code falls outside the range 200–299. Note that `HttpClient` can throw exceptions for other reasons — for example, if the request times out.

In your case  the code could be something like the following.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(apiUri.Uri);   
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Log error
    return null; // throw etc.
}
else 
{
    var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Questions<Question>>(o);
    return o;
}
```

*(You can move `var text = ...` outside of `if` if you wish.)*

---

Status code can be examined instead of calling `IsSuccessStatusCode`, if needed.

```
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) // 200
{
    throw new Exception(); / return null  et.c
}
```

Comment: Though one shouldn't throw on everything except 200 as all 2xx status codes indicate success. Errors specifically are restricted to 4xx for client errors and 5xx for server errors.